# Removing a particular value from deeply nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I have a document in the following format,

```
{  
   "entities":[  
      {  
         "info":{  
            "configId":[  
               "1234",
               "3213"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "info":{  
            "configId":[  
               "73683",
               "38297",
               "1234"
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "info":{  
            "configId":["32683" ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I remove "1234" from all the configId arrays in one update command?

I was trying the following, but it only updates the first one.

```
db.asset.update({
   "entities.info.configId": "1234"
},
{
   $pull:{
      "entities.$.info.configId":{
         $in:[ "1234" ]
      }
   }
});
```

Thanks.

Edit:

This query is finally working for me:

```
db.asset.update({
   "entities.info.configId": "1234"
},
{
   $pull:{
      "entities.$[].info.configId":{
         $in:[ "1234" ]
      }
   }
});
```